# Converting a JSON file to a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm trying to convert this json file to a javascript object, and then display it in a table format (don't worry about how the table looks at the moment, I'll fix that once this is worked out.) I can't see what I've done wrong to not be able to retrieve the json objects, as they are printed in the console when the program is run. There is a syntax error for two callbacks to the statechangehandler, but then on the next two callbacks, the json objects are printed, not quite sure why. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Question2.html:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Question 2</title>
  <script>
    function makeAjaxQueryVideo() {

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        readyStateChangeHandler(xhttp);
      };

      xhttp.open("GET", "Question2.json", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    function readyStateChangeHandler(xhttp) {
      console.log("Callback function readyStateChangeHandler is executed");
      console.log("readyState = " + xhttp.readyState);
      console.log("status = " + xhttp.status);
      console.log("responseText:");
      console.log(xhttp.responseText);

      handleStatusSuccess(xhttp);
    }

    function handleStatusFailure(xhttp) {
      var displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");
      displayDiv.innerHTML = "XMLHttpRequest failed: status " + xhttp.status;
    }

    function handleStatusSuccess(xhttp) {
      var jsonText = xhttp.responseText;

      var videoObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
      console.log(videoObj);
      console.log("title is " + videoObj.title);

      displayVideo(videoObj);
    }

    function displayVideo(videoObj) {

      var html = "<h2>Stock Market Activity " + videoObj.queryTime + "</h2>";
      html += "<table border='1'>";
      html += "<tr><th>Stock</th><th>Value</th><th>Change</th><th>Net / %</th></tr>";
      for (var i = 0; i < videoObj.result.length; i++) {
        var videoObj1 = videoObj.result[i];
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<td><b>" + videoObj1.title + "</b></td>";
        html += "<td align='right'>" + videoObj1.channel + "</td>";
        html += "<td style='color:green' align='right'>";
        html += videoObj1.view;
        html += "<img src='stockUp.png' />";
        html += "</td>";
        html += "<td align='right'>" + videoObj1.link + "%</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
      }
      html += "</table>";

      var displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");
      displayDiv.innerHTML = html;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="makeAjaxQueryVideo()">Get Search Result</button>
  <div id="display"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Question2.json:

```
{
"result": {
"searchKeyword": "Mathematics",
"video": [
  {
    "title": "Chaos Game",
    "channel": "Numberphile",
    "view": "428K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbKtFN71Lfs",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/kbKtFN71Lfs/0.jpg",
    "length": "8:38"
  },
  {
    "title": "Australian Story: Meet Eddie Woo, the maths teacher you wish 
 you'd had in high school",
    "channel": "ABC News (Australia)",
    "view": "223K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjIHB8WzJek",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/SjIHB8WzJek/0.jpg",
    "length": "28:08"
  },
  {
    "title": "Ham Sandwich Problem",
    "channel": "Numberphile",
    "view": "557K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCXmUi56rao",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCXmUi56rao/0.jpg",
    "length": "5:53"
  },
  {
    "title": "Magic Square Party Trick",
    "channel": "Numberphile",
    "view": "312K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQxCnmhqZko",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/aQxCnmhqZko/0.jpg",
    "length": "3:57"
  },
  {
    "title": "The 8 Queen Problem",
    "channel": "Numberphile",
    "view": "909K",
    "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPcBU0Z2Hj8",
    "image": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/jPcBU0Z2Hj8/0.jpg",
    "length": "7:03"
  }
]
}
}
```

Comment: Does your serialization fail ? Or you cant access objVideo.title ? Because if the json seems to be valid, videoObj has only one property : videoObj.result; your videos are in videoObj.result.video[]. but videoObj doesnt exists.

Comment: Whenever I try to access the values, they print as undefined. So I'm trying to find a way to print the correct values.

Comment: Donno, but I tried with your json, your html excepts changing videoObj.result by videoObj.result.video in your displayVideo function, and it works perfectly (when Cors problem are fixed, of course)

Comment: So you got the table output?

Comment: Definitely yes. Once solved CORS policy ( I suppose you control that through dev console ), changed the two references of videoObj.result in your function, and I got the table.

Answer (score 4):

> There is a syntax error for two callbacks to the statechangehandler, but then on the next two callbacks, the json objects are printed, not quite sure why.

You call `handleStatusSuccess` every time the state changes … even before it reaches a successful state.

You should probably use a `load` event handler instead.

```
function makeAjaxQueryVideo() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.addEventListener("load", handler)
    xhttp.open("GET", "Question2.json");
    xhttp.send();
}

function handler() {
    console.log("Callback function readyStateChangeHandler is executed");
    console.log("readyState = " + this.readyState);
    console.log("status = " + this.status);
    console.log("responseText:");
    console.log(this.responseText);
    handleStatusSuccess(this);
}
```

Comment: I did that because I always get the status code '0', yet other programs still work completely fine if I bypass the status code check for 200. I decided to just take away the check for the '200' status code so the program would move forward.